# Mocha tests stop abruptly with: Cannot find module 'pg-native'

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

Our mocha tests suddenly stop with this message on the console:

```
Cannot find module `pg-native`
```

No stack trace is shown, mocha doesn't render the normal output for the test. The test immediately stops.

If I disable the test in question, all tests run as normal.

Installing pg-native removes the error, but then mocha just hangs at that point instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3781) the problem is a result of running something that walks sequelize records in depth.

eg

```
expect(myObject).to.deep.equal(mySequelizeInstance);
```

changing to

```
expect(myObject).to.deep.equal(mySequelizeInstance.toJSON());
```

will solve it

**Why?**

There's two reasons for the above behaviour

1. Sequelize records override [native getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and so traversing certain properties causes code to be executed. In this case, one of those properties ends up down a rabbit hole that causes `require('pg-native')` to be executed (and so the error)
2. The object contains circular references, and so the code hangs traversing the infinite references. Left long enough it will eventually fail when it exhausts the stack.